# What's the extent of the problem of information leaking to exit node

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, security, relays, exit-relays

What if I let some identification information (like a page with my real name) leak in a plain http connection and the exit node captures this? Until when it be able to identify me? Till I change the circuit? Will it be able to identify me if I use it again another day? Will I have to generate another public key? (or does tor does this every time I start it?

Also, will the exit node be able to associate my identity with relay (does Tor uses different keys for my relay/hidden services?)

Answer (score 2):

The exit node only knows the middle node of the circuit, nothing upstream from it.

When you create new circuits, the exit node does not know that it is from the same source (you), unless they do traffic analysis and match behavior / patterns, or you leak the same information again.

Also, if your Tor is a relay as well as a client, you are not your own entry guard node.